# Insert html-entities in xslt

Tags: xslt, entities

I have some XMLs that contain character hex codes, e.g. it like this:

```
<char hex="AB"/>
```

Now I want to XSLT transform to display in the browser:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;#x', /char/@hex, ';', '')"/>
```

However, the output in the browser is `&amp;#xAB;` and not as I expected `&#xAB;`
so the browser does not display the character for that code (which would be `«`) but only the literal string `&#xAB;`

How can I get the XSL not to escape the ampersand?

Comment: Could you paste the result of the XSL transformation? I am curious as to how that `ÿ` came to be.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for several complete solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**This can be accomplished if you set the `output method` to `text`.**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="char">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;#x', /char/@hex, ';', '')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<char hex="AB"/>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
&#xAB;
```

Of course, with the `text` output method one needs to produce the individual characters of starting and ending tags (`<xsl:copy>`, `<xsl:copy-of>`, `<xsl:element>` and literal result elements do not produce any tags in this output method), but with some patience, everything is possible.

**One could also use DOE** (Disable Output Escaping), but this "feature" is not mandatory in the XSLT Spec. and some XSLT processors (including, I think, the one used by FF) don't implement DOE.

**Probably the best solution (not using `method="text"`) is the following**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my"
>
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="us-ascii"/>

 <my:hex>
  <code start="8">&#x80;&#x81;&#x82;&#x83;&#x84;&#x85;&#x86;&#x87;&#x88;&#x89;&#x8A;&#x8B;&#x8C;&#x8D;&#x8E;&#x8F;</code>
  <code start="9">&#x90;&#x91;&#x92;&#x93;&#x94;&#x95;&#x96;&#x97;&#x98;&#x99;&#x9A;&#x9B;&#x9C;&#x9D;&#x9E;&#x9F;</code>
  <code start="A">&#xA0;&#xA1;&#xA2;&#xA3;&#xA4;&#xA5;&#xA6;&#xA7;&#xA8;&#xA9;&#xAA;&#xAB;&#xAC;&#xAD;&#xAE;&#xAF;</code>
  <code start="B">&#xB0;&#xB1;&#xB2;&#xB3;&#xB4;&#xB5;&#xB6;&#xB7;&#xB8;&#xB9;&#xBA;&#xBB;&#xBC;&#xBD;&#xBE;&#xBF;</code>
  <code start="C">&#xC0;&#xC1;&#xC2;&#xC3;&#xC4;&#xC5;&#xC6;&#xC7;&#xC8;&#xC9;&#xCA;&#xCB;&#xCC;&#xCD;&#xCE;&#xCF;</code>
  <code start="D">&#xD0;&#xD1;&#xD2;&#xD3;&#xD4;&#xD5;&#xD6;&#xD7;&#xD8;&#xD9;&#xDA;&#xDB;&#xDC;&#xDD;&#xDE;&#xDF;</code>
  <code start="E">&#xE0;&#xE1;&#xE2;&#xE3;&#xE4;&#xE5;&#xE6;&#xE7;&#xE8;&#xE9;&#xEA;&#xEB;&#xEC;&#xED;&#xEE;&#xEF;</code>
  <code start="F">&#xF0;&#xF1;&#xF2;&#xF3;&#xF4;&#xF5;&#xF6;&#xF7;&#xF8;&#xF9;&#xFA;&#xFB;&#xFC;&#xFD;&#xFE;&#xFF;</code>
 </my:hex>

 <xsl:variable name="vHex" select="document('')/*/my:hex/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="char">
  <xsl:variable name="vchar1" select="substring(@hex,1,1)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vchar2" select="substring(@hex,2,1)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="voffset">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="number($vchar2)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$vchar2"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="count($vHex[@start = $vchar2]/preceding-sibling::*)+9"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select="substring($vHex[@start=$vchar1], $voffset, 1)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<char hex="AB"/>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
&#171;
```

This assumes that the values of the `hex` attribute are hexadecimals in the range x80 to xFF. If it is necessary to have values in a wider range, such as x00 to XFF, more `code` elements need to be accordingly added to the `my:hex` element

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is larger than just the escaping, but how about [the `disable-output-escaping` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping)?

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&amp;#x', /char/@hex, ';', '')"/>
```

Comment: I have tried that, already, but it does not affect the output in any way. I am testing in firefox, btw.