# Passing & as param to call a XSLT template

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Am stuck. I want to replace & in my string with '*spacer*'. Here is what am doing

```
<xsl:variable name="WithoutAmpersand">
  <xsl:call-template name="replaceCharsInString">
    <xsl:with-param name="stringIn" 
        select="$serviceNameWithoutCloseParanthesis"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="charsIn" select="'&amp;'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="charsOut" select="'_spacer_'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Am getting 'The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference' exception.
Please help in resolving this.

Comment: impossible to diagnose without the template you are calling.

Comment: You've provided part (but not all) of the relevant code.  Now provide some sample input (just enough to exercise the code), the output you're getting for that input, and the output you'd like from that input.  With those, people will (with some luck) be able to understand what problem you are hitting, and make suggestions.  Actually, my guess is that your input XML is not well formed and that the error you are seeing is from the XML parser, not the stylesheet processor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert html-entities in xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127044/insert-html-entities-in-xslt)